# How to set expire time along with NX/XX/GT/LT using redis module for node js

Tags: node.js, redis, hashset

I am using redis (v 3.1.2) with node and trying to set a hashkey with expire time, I am stuck with the part on where to give this additional attribute(NX/XX/GT/LT) for expire command.

```
  await client.hset(hashKey, key, JSON.stringify(value));
  await client.expire(hashKey,expire)
```

Could someone help on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Just pass a third argument to the expire method:

```js
client.expire(hashKey, expire, 'NX');
```

Comment: already tried this one, got the below error
ReplyError: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'expire' command

Comment: Which version of redis (the server) are you using? Because the NX/XX/GT/LT modifiers were added to EXPIRE in Redis v7 https://redis.io/commands/expire#history

Comment: version 3.2, but I am able to use those modifiers from CLI
only when using it from node facing issue